# What are the $\succ$ and $\prec$ operators for when used with matrices?

Tags: matrices, notation

I understand that $A\succ0$ means that "A is a positive definite matrix" (i.e.; all of the eigenvalues of A are positive).

But what does it mean when the right hand side is a different value than zero? For example, what does the expression below imply?

$$ A \succ 7.3 $$

Also, what is the name of this operator?

Comment: Normally $A > B$ means $A - B$ is positive. Perhaps, when $k$ is a number, $A > k$ actually means $A > kI$, where $I$ is the identity?

Comment: It is not an [operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28mathematics%29). It is a [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$% Preamble
  \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
  \DeclareMathOperator{\det}{det}
$
One wrote in the answer's comments, a link [What's the meaning of $\succ$ operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644731/whats-the-meaning-of-succ-operator) might be helpful. Simply, the $\succ$ sign is an analogue of classic $>$ for the non-classic cases. You and everyone other may read it ($\succ$) as $>$ simply, and it is used, or may be used, e.g. at:

1. As noted in [The answer to the respective question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/990528), $A\succ B$ may mean, depending on accepted designations, that $−$ is positive definite.
2. When $a, b\in\C$ then $a\succ b$ may denote the fact that $|a|>|b|$, where $|\cdot|$ is a classic euclidian norm, i.e. here $|x+\imath y|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Actually, this example may be transposed for similar other kind of spaces.
3. If $a\succ b$ for matrixes, then $\det a>\det b$. Why not.

Generally, it is a relation with the typical $a\succ b, b\succ c\Rightarrow a\succ c$, and with "**may not held** $a\succeq a$" any $a$ from set, e.g. Even read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preference_(economics)) if want an exact and long with abstractive examples definition. Good luck

Answer (score 9):

Often, the relation $A \succ B$ is used to indicate "$A - B$" is positive definite.

My guess is that $A \succ 7.3$ means $A \succ 7.3 I$; that is, "$A$ is symmetric, and its eigenvalues are strictly greater than $7.3$."

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I cannot answer your question completely. But I can answer the last one. The name of this operator is **succeed**. You can see all names of this math operator and its relation from this latex code, given below:

http://www.access2science.com/latex/Binary.html

Comment: I also asked meaning of $\succ$ in another question. Might be you want to check it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644731/whats-the-meaning-of-succ-operator